# Accessing USB HID from VB6

Tags: vb6

I have purchased a device measuring the CO2 content within the air. It reports the values via USB every 3 seconds. I want to process these values with VB6.

After plugging in the device, I find it in the hardware manager, listed as a Human Interface Device (HID).

By inspection of the according entry I know, that I plugged it into Port_#0003.Hub_#0003. In the events tab I read that the device with the name USB\VID_04D9&PID_A052\1.40 was configured, and that it's class GUID is {745A17A0-74D3-11D0-B6FE-00A0C90F57DA}. There is no RS/232 implementation, at least, I don't see any, so MS COMM Control is of no use (tried it anyway on all 16 allowed port numbers).

Searching through SO on information about HID tagged with [VB6], the only information I get is that using the HID API directly is a PITA.

I wanted to give it a try anyway, and attempted to reference HID.dll, only to find VB6 complaining that this DLL can not be used by VB.

Is there any way I can access my device in order to obtain and process the communicated data? How do I embark on this venture?

Comment: When you say "reference" the DLL, do you mean "add it as a reference"? If it's not a COM DLL you'll need to add Declares for any included functions. Is there a documented API for it? Is it written with C in mind?

Comment: Jim, yes, I attempted to add it as a  reference. However, it is a product written for HIDs, and is encouraged for use by MS. See this description: https://en.wikipedia.org - This page claims,that "You can use Windows' built-in HID (human interface device) drivers to communicate with devices that conform to the USB's HID class specification. There's no need for a custom driver; the device uses the drivers included in Windows. Use any programming language that supports calling API functions.": http://janaxelson.com/hidpage.htm/wiki/USB_human_interface_device_class

Comment: First link should read: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_human_interface_device_class

Answer (score 0):

I see that [Jan Axleson](http://janaxelson.com/hidpage.htm/wiki/USB_human_interface_device_class) has a link (same page in the comments) to a VB6 implementation, but all the links on the page seen to be broken -- they just reload the page. If you can track that down I'm sure it would serve your needs.

In any case, you can apparently use any supported HID device with `DirectInput`. Instance `DirectX8`, then `DirectInput8`, then `DirectInputDevice`. Enumerate devices using `GetDIDevices`, `.Acquire` the device of interest (your HID device) and explore its capabilities.

All this depends on DirectX, which is thoroughly [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee416842%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) by MS. The docs are not VB6 friendly but it's usually possible to work it out.

Comment: Thanks Jim. However, DirectX8 fails to install on Win 8.1, and says it requires Win 9x, ..., Vista.

Comment: @Herb Just install the latest DX version that works for your OS (11?). All the earlier interfaces should be subsumed in the new versions, or there will be equivalent ones.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't for the faint of heart using any language if you don't have complete vendor docs.  You'll probably have to use a USB sniffer to capture raw packets while in use with the vendor's software.  From there the hard work of scratching and guessing begins.

See [[VB6] TEMPer Gold USB HID Thermometer Class](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?685671-VB6-TEMPer-Gold-USB-HID-Thermometer-Class) for an example of code written in VB6 to work with such a device.  Even getting that to work was a lot of cut and try even though others had posted sample C code and some ruminations on the USB packets exchanged. It sounds like you'll have even more work to do unless somebody else has already done some of the heavy lifting for you.

HID.DLL is not an ActiveX library.  It has no typelib embedded.  As far as I know there is no external typelib available either.  So there is nothing to set a reference to anyway.

Not only that, it isn't even a COM library but a raw plain old standard DLL.

I think you could be in far over your head.  Unless the vendor offers an API library you might be out of luck unless you have the time and the tools to do the necessary research and development.  If the vendor offers decent low-level docs it would save some effort but that seems unlikely since they seldom do.

Comment: Thanks for getting me started. I won't mark your answer as the solution yet, until I make some serious progress, which I hope I will. +1